# Using a custom (ttf) font in CSS

Tags: css, fonts, truetype

I have a mac, and have installed a font called "7 Segment" (it shows up in Font Book). When I use `font-family: "7 Segment";` I get Helvetica (or similar) rather than the browser's default font, but it still isn't showing the correct font. The page only needs to be shown on this computer. How would I use the font on this page? Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% positive the font has been registered as a system font?  Many font applications don't always do so, as too many registered fonts can result in a performance penalty.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to use the css-property font-face to declare your font. Have a look at this fancy site: http://www.font-face.com/

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyHelvetica;
  src: local("Helvetica Neue Bold"),
       local("HelveticaNeue-Bold"),
       url(MgOpenModernaBold.ttf);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

See also: [MDN @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face#Examples)

Comment: Not in this case: `The page only needs to be shown on this computer.` this is possible without using `font-face`

Comment: Stil... Why would it be bad to use the proper css-way? It doesn't matter if it's local of not, this is the way it's done.

Comment: I removed the downvote because it may indeed end up being the best workaround. Still, it should be possible without it

Answer (score 0):

This is not a system font. this font is not supported in other systems. you can use [font-face](http://www.font-face.com/), convert font from this [Site](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) or from [this](http://www.font2web.com/)

[image]

Comment: Read the question. `The page only needs to be shown on this computer.`

Comment: i think downloaded font have some problem . i got the correct font using this font-family: "7 Segment"; . but i am using windows . can you please download one more time and install. check the above image

Comment: @Sanooj font-face is still pre-launch.

Comment: @Sanooj Thanks for the idea