# Use a custom font that a user does not have installed

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use web-fonts legally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805324/how-to-use-web-fonts-legally)
>   [Using a custom (ttf) font in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512468/using-a-custom-ttf-font-in-css)

Just a simple one - wondering if I say, find a nice font to use that the user is probably not going to have installed, is there a way I can use it without it being installed on a users computer? I mean without making it an image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [CSS's @font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson Thank you for pointing that out. Updated with a newer more authoritative source

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use CSS3 @font-face. You'll have to upload font files inside your server in special formats. Be sure that font's licence allows that.

You can find selection of free-to-use fonts on http://www.fontsquirrel.com/, which also provides generator for CSS properties and converts font files to needed formats.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS use the following. You will need to convert your .ttf to a .eot to work with IE properly.

```
@font-face { 
   font-family: "SFSpeedway"; 
    /* IE */
    src: url(./fonts/fontname.eot');
    /* IE */

    /* Not IE */
    src: local("SF Speedwaystar Condensed"), url(./fonts/fontname.ttf');
    format("truetype");
    /* Not IE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css's @font-face if the font is available that way - keep in mind that using it affects your page loading time and this could also affect performances on slow (mobile) connections.

otherwise it's safer to have fallback fonts:

```
font-family: helvetica neue, arial, serif;
```

you could also look at cufon but I personally don't like it