# How do I add fonts .ttf files to grails project

Tags: grails, fonts, grails-controller

I have custom font file. How do I add it the grails project. Can I use ${resource(dir: , file:'')} for adding it?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not limited to Grails, since you use CSS to do it. [There's this related question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512468/using-a-custom-ttf-font-in-css), it explains that you need to [use @font-face](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/).

You can use relative paths and let Grails resources handle it you:

Put your font in *web-app/fonts* (create the directory)

Add to your css (considering the file Delicious-Roman.ttf, replace to yours):

```
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; src: url('../fonts/Delicious-Roman.ttf'); } 
@font-face { font-family: Delicious; font-weight: bold; src: url('../Delicious-Bold.ttf'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

Download your font from any website.
got to [webFont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). 
It will generate a zip file . in which got to your .css file and copy and paste code in your web within style tag. also paste all file within same directory. it will run all browser.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Philosopher';
src: url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.eot');
src: url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body{
font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Philosopher";
}
```

this code snippet is true for philospher font. You can use any font based on this example.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into `web-app` dir.
You can create directory like web-app/fonts and reference it as `/fonts/yourfont.ttf`  or as `${resource(dir: 'fonts', file: yourfont.ttf}`
Notice that the first works only if you run your application in a root context.