# Inline Custom CSS Fonts In HTML5

Tags: css, html, fonts

I am trying to use a custom font in a webpage. I however know next to nothing about HTML5 and CSS. I want **1** h1 tag to have a custom font. I have the .ttf file in the same folder as the webpage. I tried this with no success:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center"; font-family="MinecrafterReg.ttf">Welcome to Ben's Minecraft</h1>
```

Could anyone else help me?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512468/using-a-custom-ttf-font-in-css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Stick this in the style tags:

```
@font-face {
font-family: MinecrafterReg;
src: url(MinecrafterReg.ttf);
font-weight:400;
```

Then stick this in the h1 tag:

```
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: MinecrafterReg">Welcome to Ben's Minecraft</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays you can place an `@import` at the top of your `style` block:

```
<style>
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
</style>
```

Answer (score -4):

This is not how you should use a custom font on a website. First, you should use an external style sheet and have all your CSS in that. Using inline styles is not a great practice. Second, I do not think you can link to a .ttf file as you want. Notice also that your code had wrong inline format. font-family: not =. Also, the whole inline style needs to be in quotes. style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;"

That being said - you could link your font in your 'head' of your document and then use inline styles to style h1. Here is a way to do it with a google font. Hope this helps!

```
<head>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;">Welcome to Ben's Minecraft</h1>
```

Comment: When optimizing for performance inlining styles is actually very helpful.

Comment: Please remove your answer

Comment: See this https://web.dev/font-best-practices/#inline-font-declarations

Answer (score -5):

font-family:url('https://s3-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/fonts/FloydsnirLTStd-Rmands.otf'); in Inline style css

Comment: How would that work and why is it supposed to help with the described problem?